# MySQL sub query in Laravel, how to join queries and add second query's result as a new column to first query?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have two tables:

```
- PRODUCTS (having: ID, NAME, PRICE)
- LIKES (having: ID, PRODID, NAME)
```

I would like to query the first table while counting (and returning as a new column) in a sub query all the likes the product has. How could I combine the following queries?

```
$products = DB::table('PRODUCTS')
                  ->get();

$likes = DB::table('LIKES')
                  ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                  ->where('PRODID', '=', 'product id from first table')
                  ->get();
```

How could I achieve this using Laravel queries?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't do it as a subquery, join the 2 tables together and group by on the fields from product table.

Comment: I have tried, but the LIKES table has multiple rows with the same PRODID, so when I join the two the rows won't match. The query will create duplicate rows in my PRODUCTS table.

Comment: This is why you use the group by. I can give you the solution in sql, but you need to translate it into laravel because I do not know that.

Comment: thanks, I try this way.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you specifically asked for but as an alternative, this would be extremely easy to handle with Eloquent.

```
$products = Product::with('likes');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo 'Number of likes: '.$product->likes->count();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a join with a group by clause, rather than a subquery. This way you can get the counts for all products in one go, you do not have to query the counts one by one. The sql looks like as follows:

```
select p.id, p.name, p.price, count(l.id) as likecount
from products p
left join likes l on p.id=l.prodid
group by p.id, p.name, p.price
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$likes = DB::table('LIKES')
      ->join('PRODUCTS', 'LIKES.PRODID', '=', 'PRODUCTS.id') 
      ->select('LIKES.*') 
      ->where('PRODUCTS.id', '=', 3)      
      ->get();
$total_like = count($likes);
```